# Play youtube while recording

Tags: javascript

I created javascript code for recording audio files.
I would like to play a youtube file while recording, so I need to add the play function to my record function, but it dosn't work.
What exactly do I miss?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>mini demo12
    </title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    ul { list-style: none; }
    #recordingslist audio { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>


  <iframe id="mainVideo" width="640" height="390" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9H2oY_85q8U?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <BR>
  <button onclick="startRecording(this);">record</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>stop</button>
  <button onclick="startPlaying(this)">play</button>

  <h2>Tracks</h2>
  <ul id="recordingslist"></ul>

  <h2>Log</h2>
  <pre id="log"></pre>


  function startRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.record();
    button.disabled = true;
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
    __log('Recording...');
  }

   <script src="recorder.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why `startRecording` function isn't wrapped in `<script>` tag? looks to me like everything works besides this small detail.

Comment: It does. I removed some of the code from the example. But I still don't know how to trigger playing the youtube file that in the iframe, from the recording function. can you help on that?

Comment: Check YouTube API documentation - https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference there's pretty much everything you need in "Getting Started" section